# Purpose of Pragma Inline in specification files

Tags: inline, ada, pragma, gnat

Many subprogram declarations of GNAT Standard Library uses Pragma Inline in their specification files and I want to know how it work because other modules use only this specification during compilation and not body?

Comment: See [ARM 6.3.2](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-6-3-2.html).

Comment: See also the [GNAT doc](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/building_executable_programs_with_gnat.html) about inlining, esp. the `-gnatn` switch.

Comment: In C++, for the compiler to inline a function, its definition must be in a header file. In Ada, after all, when compiling a module, only the specification files of with'ed packages  are used, while their definitions may not even exist yet? There is no mention of this in the section of the manual you mentioned.

Comment: @Андрей Гриценко - This is indeed an interesting curiosity. The compiler must indeed be able to peek into the body to grab the actual implementation in order to inline it. If the body is not available (as source), then, AFAIK, inlining will not be possible although I'm not sure about the potential role of LTO here.

Comment: Thank you! I found comprehensive information about it here: https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/gnat_and_program_execution.html

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188), perhaps citing the sources mentioned above.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/ada/inline.adb) may give some insight as to what GNAT takes into consideration when inlining.